# Is $\zeta^{3,1}\simeq \Bbb M^{3,1}?$ Why or why not?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, mathematical-physics, semi-riemannian-geometry

A semi-riemannian manifold $\zeta^{3,1}:=\zeta^{1,1}\times \zeta^{1,0} \times \zeta^{1,0}.$ I calculated the non degenerate product metric of it: $ds^2=\frac{drdt}{rt}+\frac{du}{u}+\frac{dv}{v}.$ Previously I had studied $\zeta^{1,1}$ and came to understand that it is diffeomorphic to the Minkowski plane, $\Bbb M^{1,1}.$

So with the correspondence $\zeta^{1,1}\simeq \Bbb M^{1,1}$ I wondered if $\zeta^{3,1}$ is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb M^{3,1}.$

> Is $\zeta^{3,1}\simeq \Bbb M^{3,1}?$ Why or why not?

To answer this I took each term in the product metric $ds^2$ (above) and performed a change in coordinates on each.

What I'm getting after the coordinate change is $ds^2=drdt+du+dv$. So it suffices to show whether this metric is related to Lorentz metric $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2-dt^2$ by some euclidean transformation $-$ a rotation possibly?

---

Here's how I tried to calculate the metric of $\zeta^{3,1}:$

I first calculated the metric of $\zeta^{1,1}$ by pulling back the Lorentz metric $ds^2=dxdy.$

Let $u=\frac{dr}{r}$ and $f=\frac{dt}{t}.$

Then I tried to use the same argument for the 1-dimensional manifolds $\zeta^{1,0}$ but as per the comments maybe I'm misunderstanding something about this being a proper non-degenerate metric: $ds^2=\frac{drdt}{rt}+\frac{du}{u}+\frac{dv}{v}.$

All of this makes me think I have not properly calculated the non-degenerate metric of $\zeta^{3,1}$ properly.

I'm pretty stuck so any help would be great.

Comment: Hmm, in regards to the ${\rm d}s^2$ equation, is it really possible for the difference between two $2$-forms to be a combination of $1$-forms? I don't see how that's possible.

Comment: @runway44 Could you add more details? I am a beginner..

Comment: What is $\zeta^{3,1}$ and how did you calculate the metric on it? You didn't add any details yourself!

Comment: Tried to add more details

Comment: Can you provide the definitions of $\zeta^{p,q}$ and $\Bbb M^{p,q}$? I'm guessing that if $\zeta^{1,1}$ is parametrized by $x,y$ with $ds^2=dxdy$ and the two $\zeta^{1,0}$s are parametrized by $w$ and $z$ then the product metric on $\zeta^{1,1}\times\zeta^{1,0}\times\zeta^{1,0}$ ought to be  given by $ds^2=dxdy+dw^2+dz^2$. And if you change coordinates with $x=u+v$ and $y=-u+v$ then this becomes the Lorentz metric $-du^2+dv^2+dw^2+dz^2$.

Comment: yeah I'll provide the definitions as soon as I can today, thanks for your helpful comment.